# lighthouse-ci keeps failing when using https://localhost url

Tags: https, localhost, puppeteer, lighthouse

I ran my application locally with production assets. and then I ran the `lhci autorun`.
I set `"headful": true` so I can see the chrome opens properly and the website automatically loads and closes properly. However, the lhci autorun fails with the following error:

```
Run #1...failed!
Error: Lighthouse failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.child.on.code
    node_modules/@lhci/cli/src/collect/lighthouse-runner.js:103:21

  "runWarnings": [
    "Chrome prevented page load with an interstitial. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests."
  ],
  "runtimeError": {
    "code": "CHROME_INTERSTITIAL_ERROR",
    "message": "Chrome prevented page load with an interstitial. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests."
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you share your lighthouserc file here. May be some config is misconfigured.